# passing variable from wpf window1 to wpf window2 using c#

Tags: c#, wpf

in my WPF `MainWindow` I get from user file path and it saves into `string dirPath` variable.
Now I want to use `dirPath` variable in another WPF Window which is called `PictureViewer`.

So my question is: How can I pass that variable which is in MainWindow to another Window so I can use it there?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `dirPath` an attribute of `MainWindow` ? Is `PictureViewer` window owned by `MainWindow` ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: do the two windows exist in the same Application? Is one window opening the other?

Comment: Questions on SO asking for coding assistance require you to show your attempts or research, [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are opening your `PictureViewer Window` from your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file, you can simply do this:

In your `PictureViewer` class:

```
private string dirPath;

public PictureViewer(string dirPath)
{
    this.dirPath = dirPath;
}
```

Then in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
PictureViewer pictureViewer = new PictureViewer(dirPathFromMainWindow);
pictureViewer.Show();
```